# Prove that taking $2$ pairs from set of pairs of elements of $[n]$ is given by: $3 \times \binom{n+1}{4}$.

Tags: combinatorics

I am modifying the problem from an mse post at: [Verify that $\binom{n+1}{4} = \frac{\left(\substack{\binom{n}{2}\\{\displaystyle2}}\right)}{3}$ for $n \geq 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1364821/424260). I hope the modification keeps the problem intact.

 The real issue is the inability  to understand the selected answer there.

---

For the case of taking $2$ pairs from the set of possible pairs of element from a set of $n$ elements, have two options. 
First option is to get overlapping pairs, while the second option is to get disjoint pairs.
Given a small set with $n=4 = \{A,B,C,D\}$; both options draw from the possible set of members: $AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD$.
The options for the overlapping pairs are: 
1. $AB,BC$
2. $AB,BD$
3. $AB,AC$
4. $AB,AD$
5. $AC,CD$ 
6. $AC,BC$ 
7. $AC,AD$
8. $AD,BD$ 
9. $AD,CD$ 
10. $BC,BD$ 
11. $BC,CD$ 
12. $CD,BD$ 
But, the disjoint case has $3$ options : 
a. $AB,CD$ 
b. $AC,BD$ 
c. $AD,BC$

I want to know how the above division in each of the two cases, for general case or for my small example is given by $3 \times \binom{n+1}{4}$.

Comment: In your example, ${{n+1} \choose 4} = {5 \choose 4} = 5$. How does that relate to taking two pairs?

Comment: @Théophile I hope you would not mind that I have taken this problem from an mse post, and my understanding of the problem is this much only. The post is at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1364821/424260

Comment: Ah. In other words, are you asking for an explanation for the accepted answer to that question?

Comment: @Théophile Yes, the explanation given is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to pick $4$ elements from a total of $n+1$ elements.

We keep the first element ,$f$, apart and focus on the other $n$ elements. Call the set of $n$ elements $S$.

We consider the set of all pairs of elements in $S$, call it $P$. We can choose two pairs from $P$, call them $\{A, B\}$ and $\{C, D\}$.

The first case is if $\{A, B\}$ and $\{C, D\}$ overlaps, in that case, we pick the first element that was separated initially, $f$, as one of the $4$ elements that are chosen as well.

The second case is if $\{A, B\}$ and $\{C,D\}$ do not overlap, in that case, we do not pick the first element.

By using this procedure, we could have chosen $4$ elements from $n+1$ elements. However, we have counted elements multiple times and we have to consider that.

In the first case if we have chosen $\{f,e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. It is equally likely that the repeated element is $e_i$ where $i=1,2,3$.

In the second case, if we have selected $\{e_1,e_2, e_3, e_4\}$, $e_4$ is equally likely to have been paired with $e_i$ where $i=1,2,3$.

Hence $$\binom{n+1}4=\frac13 \binom{\binom{n}2}{2}$$

for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Please elaborate more, particularly in light of me finding $15 (=12+3)$ cases in my post for $n=4$ case. The sum of the two cases is satisfying the equality.

Comment: case $1, 3, 6$ gives you the same set, they don't have $D$. Try to group the others as well and you can see that every case is counted multiple times by $3$ times.

Comment: Yes, for the overlapping cases have each triple occurring $3$ times: $A,B,C: 1,3,6; A,B,D: 2,4,8; A,C,D : 5,7,9; B,C,D: 10,11,12$. I am confused about the role of disjoint case's $3$ options, except that all the four elements occur $3$ times.

Comment: They form $ABCD$, we counted it $3$ times too.

Comment: In the answer's last line, the lhs term yield for $n=4$, value $5$; & the rhs term yields $nC2 = 4C2= 6, 6C2 = 15, \frac{15}3 =5$. So, is it the sum of both the disjoint & overlapping cases being taken up?

Comment: yes, we have included the sum in the expression.